# MEAN.JS stack $http.post().success() passing variables into success() anonymous function scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, mean-stack

I'm trying to make this work:

```
$http.post('/route/path', {'username': $scope.threadedUsers[currentIndex].name}).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.threadedUsers[currentIndex].ID = data._id;
        $scope.threadedUsers[currentIndex].pic = data.profile_picture[0];
    }).
    error(function(data) {
        //error stuff here
    });
```

$scope.threadedUsers is an array of JSON objects being dynamically populated
so $scope.threadedUsers[0] = { 'ID': '', 'pic': '', 'messages': [], 'lastTimestamp': '' }

currentIndex is a local variable that refers to which index of the $scope.threadedUsers array that is currently being operated on.

The problem is that inside the success anonymous function, currentIndex is in a new scope.  Now I could put currentIndex in $scope, but that seems like bad practice considering this would be the ONLY reason to do that.

Is there anyway to pass in an external value to the success callback function (for the index)?  or is the only way to make currentIndex a $scope variable?

Comment: I don't understand your point. but whatever it is, it doesn't seem a big problem. elaborate more, i can help. Whatever i've understood according to that,i'd suggest you to use model like $scope.threadedUsers={}; now use it like $scope.threadedUsers.Id=data.id, $scope.threadedUsers.pic=data.profile_picture[0];

Comment: From your code, the `currentIndex` should also available in the success callback. Does it not or what is your problem exactly?

Comment: @micronyks - I've elaborated a bit more, the threadedUsers is an array of dynamically created JSON objects.

Comment: @runTarm - currentIndex works outside of the success callback perfectly, however inside of the success callback, it does not.  Replacing '[currentIndex]' with '[0]' causes the first element to be populated

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the problem is that a value of the `currentIndex` at the time a request is made and in the success callback are different, right?

Comment: @runTarm - Now I'm even more confused.  You are correct, currentIndex does indeed keep its value.  I changed it to $scope.threadedUsers[0].ID = currentIndex;  and it sets the ID correctly...but $scope.threadedUsers[currentIndex].ID = 'ANYTHING'; doesn't work still.

Comment: What is the value of the `currentIndex` you see? I think you should include more code, so that other people will be able to help you easier.

Comment: ahh...I see, so since the last value that currentIndex is set to is out of bounds, it's probably trying to set a non-existent variable by the time that request actually gets processed.  So back to my original idea....is there anyway to pass the current value of currentIndex into the function? ...So when the function is executed it knows the correct index of the array to operate on?

Comment: I'm still confused. do you want to map 'data' value to threadedUsers array with indexing? tell me which kind of output you want... if possible write down your desired ouptput here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting an extremely common problem/misconception with javascript for/while loops, which are synchronous and asynchronous functions. By the time the asynchronous function, in this case the HTTP post callback executes, the synchronous loop has run to completion and the loop counter variable is already at the final ending value.

Just refactor your code into a helper method that processes a single user.

```
function updateUser($scope, user) {
  $http.post('/route/path', {'username': user.name}).
    success(function(data) {
      user.ID = data._id;
      user.pic = data.profile_picture[0];
  }).
  error(function(data) {
    //error stuff here
  });
}

//Here's the code you omitted but is essential to your question
var updateInScope = updateUser.bind(null, $scope);
$scope.threadedUsers.forEach(updateInScope);
```

Comment: Yeah, I see now why nothing was changing, the currentIndex value gets set at the end of the loop, so the index was probably out of bounds by the time the callback function gets processed.  I don't have time to try this now, but when I try this, if it works, I will mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks, re-structuring in this way solved my problem.  I appreciate you taking your time to set me straight.  Funny thing is, I was planning to move it into a function after I got it working in order to get JSLint from complaining about me creating a function within a loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem occurred because the `currentIndex` is in some for-loop.

There are many ways to avoid it, one of them is to refactor the code like the Peter Lyons' answer.

An alternative, you could rememeber the `currentIndex` inside a closure like this:

```
(function (rememberedIndex) {
    $http.post('/route/path', {'username': $scope.threadedUsers[rememberedIndex].name}).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.threadedUsers[rememberedIndex].ID = data._id;
        $scope.threadedUsers[rememberedIndex].pic = data.profile_picture[0];
    }).
    error(function(data) {
        //error stuff here
    });
}(currentIndex));
```

Actually, you could also use the same variable name `currentIndex`, but it might cause a confusion to someone that see the code later ..

```
(function (currentIndex) {
    $http.post('/route/path', {'username': $scope.threadedUsers[currentIndex].name}).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.threadedUsers[currentIndex].ID = data._id;
        $scope.threadedUsers[currentIndex].pic = data.profile_picture[0];
    }).
    error(function(data) {
        //error stuff here
    });
}(currentIndex));
```

Comment: I think I'll stick with the helper function, it's easier to read and I don't have the time to learn about closures at the moment.  I appreciate the detailed response though and will definitely look into closures down the road when I'm not pressed to meet a deadline :P